# Memory Leak - Not Sure How/Where to CFRelease() CFSet

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, usb, core-foundation, iokit

I'm yet again struggling with a memory leak, and need some help figuring this one out. I know (or am pretty sure) the CFSet(s) are the problem here.

I assume I need to CFRelease() them, but am not sure how to accomplish this since I also need to return a CFSet in USBDeviceCount(). Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Here's the code (which seemingly works great! except for the leaks):

```
// New USB device has been added (callback function)
static void Handle_DeviceMatchingCallback(void *inContext,
                                          IOReturn inResult,
                                          void *inSender,
                                          IOHIDDeviceRef inIOHIDDeviceRef){

    // Log the device ID & device count
    NSLog(@"\nNew USB device: %p\nDevice count: %ld",
          (void *)inIOHIDDeviceRef,
          USBDeviceCount(inSender));

}

// USB device has been removed (callback function)
static void Handle_DeviceRemovalCallback(void *inContext,
                                         IOReturn inResult,
                                         void *inSender,
                                         IOHIDDeviceRef inIOHIDDeviceRef){

    // Log the device ID & device count
    NSLog(@"\nUSB device removed: %p\nDevice count: %ld",
          (void *)inIOHIDDeviceRef,
          USBDeviceCount(inSender));

}

// Counts the number of devices in the device set (includes all USB devices that match dictionary)
static long USBDeviceCount(IOHIDManagerRef HIDManager)
{

    // The device set includes all USB devices that match our matching dictionary. Fetch it.
    CFSetRef devSet = IOHIDManagerCopyDevices(HIDManager);

    // The devSet will be NULL if there are 0 devices, so only try to count the devices if devSet exists
    if(devSet) return CFSetGetCount(devSet);

    // There were no matching devices (devSet was NULL), so return a count of 0
    return 0;
}

- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    // Create an HID Manager
    IOHIDManagerRef HIDManager = IOHIDManagerCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                    kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone);

    // Create a Matching Dictionary
    CFMutableDictionaryRef matchDict = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(
                                                                 kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                 2,
                                                                 &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                                                                 &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

    // Specify a device manufacturer in the Matching Dictionary
    CFDictionarySetValue(matchDict,
                         CFSTR(kIOHIDTransportKey),
                         CFSTR("USB"));

    // Register the Matching Dictionary to the HID Manager
    IOHIDManagerSetDeviceMatching(HIDManager, matchDict);


    // Register a callback for USB device detection with the HID Manager
    IOHIDManagerRegisterDeviceMatchingCallback(HIDManager, &Handle_DeviceMatchingCallback, NULL);
    // Register a callback fro USB device removal with the HID Manager
    IOHIDManagerRegisterDeviceRemovalCallback(HIDManager, &Handle_DeviceRemovalCallback, NULL);

    // Register the HID Manager on our app’s run loop
    IOHIDManagerScheduleWithRunLoop(HIDManager, CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);

    // Open the HID Manager
    IOReturn IOReturn = IOHIDManagerOpen(HIDManager, kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone);
    if(IOReturn) NSLog(@"IOHIDManagerOpen failed."); // Couldn't open the HID manager!


    CFSetRef devSet = IOHIDManagerCopyDevices(HIDManager);

    CFRelease(devSet);
    CFRelease(matchDict);

}
```

[image: leaks]

**For completeness, here is the solution I was able to implement with Carl's help (thanks, Carl!!):**

AppDelegate.h:

```
- (void) updateConnectedUSBs;
@property(retain) __attribute__((NSObject)) IOHIDManagerRef hidManager;
@property (strong) NSSet *usbDeviceSet;
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
// New USB device has been added (callback function)
static void Handle_DeviceMatchingCallback(void *inContext,
                                          IOReturn inResult,
                                          void *inSender,
                                          IOHIDDeviceRef inIOHIDDeviceRef){

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate updateConnectedUSBs];

}

// USB device has been removed (callback function)
static void Handle_DeviceRemovalCallback(void *inContext,
                                         IOReturn inResult,
                                         void *inSender,
                                         IOHIDDeviceRef inIOHIDDeviceRef){

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate updateConnectedUSBs];

}

- (void) updateConnectedUSBs {

    CFSetRef devSet = IOHIDManagerCopyDevices(_hidManager);
    self.usbDeviceSet = CFBridgingRelease(devSet);
    NSLog(@"%@",self.usbDeviceSet);

}

- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification 
{

    _hidManager = IOHIDManagerCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone);

    // Create a Matching Dictionary
    CFMutableDictionaryRef matchDict = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(
                                                                 kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                 2,
                                                                 &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                                                                 &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

    // Specify a device manufacturer in the Matching Dictionary
    CFDictionarySetValue(matchDict,
                         CFSTR(kIOHIDTransportKey),
                         CFSTR("USB"));

    // Register the Matching Dictionary to the HID Manager
    IOHIDManagerSetDeviceMatching(_hidManager, matchDict);

    // Register a callback for USB device detection with the HID Manager
    IOHIDManagerRegisterDeviceMatchingCallback(_hidManager, &Handle_DeviceMatchingCallback, NULL);
    // Register a callback fro USB device removal with the HID Manager
    IOHIDManagerRegisterDeviceRemovalCallback(_hidManager, &Handle_DeviceRemovalCallback, NULL);

    // Register the HID Manager on our app’s run loop
    IOHIDManagerScheduleWithRunLoop(_hidManager, CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);

    // Open the HID Manager
    IOReturn IOReturn = IOHIDManagerOpen(_hidManager, kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone);
    if(IOReturn) NSLog(@"IOHIDManagerOpen failed."); // Couldn't open the HID manager!

    CFRelease(matchDict);

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the count before releasing the set.  (This was the way all NSObject subclasses worked before ARC, via the -release method.)

```
if (devSet) {
     long count = (long)CFSetGetCount(devSet);
     CFRelease(devSet);
     return count;
}
```

If you can use the CFAutorelease() function, that is another way which you could call right after creating it, and it will be collected at the end of the run loop.  But using CFRelease directly is a bit more efficient if it doesn't add any complexity to the code.  Autoreleasing early can sometimes avoid multiple checks later on if there are multiple returns.

You also need to CFRelease the HIDManager instance, I believe.

Comment: Carl - Thanks very much for your response and explanation. Your suggestion did indeed significantly reduce the amount of leaked objects.  

I had originally tried doing `CFRelease(HIDManager);` at the end of `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, but releasing HIDManager caused the call back functions to never run.

When I do release HIDManager, all of the memory leaks stop as far as I can tell. How can I release HIDManager, but maintain the callbacks when the # of USB devices attached to the Mac changes?

The goal here is to perform an action whenever a USB device is connected/disconnected.

Comment: @x74353 - Ah yes, if you need to keep the HIDManager around for the lifetime of the app, leaking it is no big deal.  The usual way then would be to keep a reference in a property/instance variable of the app delegate itself, which would retain it as a property to then be released in its dealloc method (which of course will never come in normal circumstances).  After setting the property, you could then release the local reference. That way, you would avoid warnings if you ever run the clang analyzer (Product->Analyze from the Xcode menu), which will usually flag leaked instances like this.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks again, Carl! I've marked your answer as the solution and have updated the original post with new code incorporating your answer and suggestions.