# Memory Leak Using IOKit (Adapted From USBPrivateDataSample)

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, usb, core-foundation, iokit

Well. I'm back with another memory leak question. I recently asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50311785/memory-leak-not-sure-how-where-to-cfrelease-cfset), but it turns out that code doesn't entirely do what I am trying to accomplish (which is to perform an action whenever any USB device connects/disconnects, and not just when an HID devices does).

I've started over from scratch, and have adapted Apple's [USBPrivateDataSample](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/USBPrivateDataSample/Listings/USBPrivateDataSample_c.html) and some of GitHub project [ORSSerialPort](https://gist.github.com/armadsen/5131559) into something that seems to work just like I want it to -- **except** --there are memory leaks. :(

I've tried applying the knowledge gained from my previous posts about dealing with memory leaks, but I'm stuck again. What am I missing? Thanks very much in advance.

Here's the code:

```
 **AppDelegate.h:**

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong) NSMutableDictionary *deviceDictionary;
@end


 **AppDelegate.m:**

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#include <IOKit/usb/IOUSBLib.h>

typedef struct DeviceData 
{
    io_object_t             notification;
    CFStringRef             deviceName;
    CFStringRef             serialNum;

} DeviceData;


static IONotificationPortRef    gNotifyPort;
static io_iterator_t            gAddedIter;
static CFRunLoopRef             gRunLoop;


@implementation AppDelegate


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{

    self.deviceDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    CFMutableDictionaryRef  matchingDict;
    CFRunLoopSourceRef      runLoopSource;
    kern_return_t           kr;

    matchingDict = IOServiceMatching(kIOUSBDeviceClassName);

    if (matchingDict == NULL)
    {

        fprintf(stderr, "IOServiceMatching returned NULL.\n");

    }

    // Create a notification port and add its run loop event source to our run loop
    // This is how async notifications get set up.

    gNotifyPort = IONotificationPortCreate(kIOMasterPortDefault);
    runLoopSource = IONotificationPortGetRunLoopSource(gNotifyPort);

    gRunLoop = CFRunLoopGetCurrent();
    CFRunLoopAddSource(gRunLoop, runLoopSource, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);

    // Now set up a notification to be called when a device is first matched by I/O Kit.
    kr = IOServiceAddMatchingNotification(gNotifyPort,                  // notifyPort
                                          kIOFirstMatchNotification,    // notificationType
                                          matchingDict,                 // matching
                                          DeviceAdded,                  // callback
                                          NULL,                         // refCon
                                          &gAddedIter                   // notification
                                          );

    // Iterate once to get already-present devices and arm the notification
    DeviceAdded(NULL, gAddedIter);

    // Start the run loop. Now we'll receive notifications.
    CFRunLoopRun();

    // can't do these, causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash
    //CFRelease(matchingDict);
    //CFRelease(gNotifyPort);
    //CFRelease(kr);

    CFRelease(runLoopSource);
    CFRelease(gRunLoop);

}


void DeviceNotification(void *refCon, io_service_t service, natural_t messageType, void *messageArgument)
{

    kern_return_t   kr;
    DeviceData   *deviceDataRef = (DeviceData *) refCon;

    if (messageType == kIOMessageServiceIsTerminated)
    {

        kr = IOObjectRelease(deviceDataRef->notification);

        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        if ((deviceDataRef->serialNum) && (deviceDataRef->deviceName))
        {

            // remove device from dict
            [appDelegate updateDeviceDict:
             (__bridge NSString *)deviceDataRef->serialNum:
             (__bridge NSString *)deviceDataRef->deviceName:
             NO];

        }

        free(deviceDataRef);

    }

}


void DeviceAdded(void *refCon, io_iterator_t iterator)
{

    kern_return_t   kr;
    io_service_t    usbDevice;

    while ((usbDevice = IOIteratorNext(iterator)))
    {

        io_name_t   deviceName;
        CFStringRef deviceNameCF;

        DeviceData  *deviceDataRef = NULL;

        // Add some app-specific information about this device.
        // Create a buffer to hold the data.
        deviceDataRef = malloc(sizeof(DeviceData));
        bzero(deviceDataRef, sizeof(DeviceData));

        // Get the USB device's name.
        kr = IORegistryEntryGetName(usbDevice, deviceName);
        if (KERN_SUCCESS != kr)
        {

            deviceName[0] = '\0';

        }

        CFMutableDictionaryRef usbProperties = 0;
        if (IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties(usbDevice, &usbProperties, kCFAllocatorDefault, kNilOptions) != KERN_SUCCESS)
        {

            IOObjectRelease(usbDevice);
            continue;

        }

        NSDictionary *properties = CFBridgingRelease(usbProperties);

        NSString *serialNum = properties[(__bridge NSString *)CFSTR("USB Serial Number")];
        NSNumber *builtIn = properties[(__bridge NSString *)CFSTR("Built-In")];
        deviceNameCF = CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault, deviceName, kCFStringEncodingASCII);

        if (builtIn.integerValue != 1)
        {

            // Save the device's name to our private data.
            deviceDataRef->deviceName = deviceNameCF;
            deviceDataRef->serialNum = (__bridge CFStringRef)(serialNum);

            AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

            [appDelegate updateDeviceDict:
             (__bridge NSString *)deviceDataRef->serialNum:
             (__bridge NSString *)deviceDataRef->deviceName:
             YES];

        }

        // Register for an interest notification of this device being removed. Use a reference to our
        // private data as the refCon which will be passed to the notification callback.
        kr = IOServiceAddInterestNotification(gNotifyPort,                      // notifyPort
                                              usbDevice,                        // service
                                              kIOGeneralInterest,               // interestType
                                              DeviceNotification,               // callback
                                              deviceDataRef,                   // refCon
                                              &(deviceDataRef->notification)   // notification
                                              );

        // Done with this USB device; release the reference added by IOIteratorNext
        kr = IOObjectRelease(usbDevice);

    }

}

- (void) updateDeviceDict : (NSString *) deviceSerial : (NSString *) deviceName : (bool) keepDevice
{

    if (deviceName)
    {

        if ((!deviceSerial) || ([deviceSerial isEqualToString:@""])) deviceSerial = deviceName;

        @try
        {

            //@throw [[NSException alloc] initWithName:@"test" reason:@"test" userInfo:nil];

            // if the device needs to be added
            if ((keepDevice) && (deviceSerial))
            {

                if (![self.deviceDictionary objectForKey:deviceSerial])
                {

                    [self.deviceDictionary setObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:deviceName, @"name", nil] forKey:deviceSerial];
                    NSLog(@"Device added: %@", deviceName);

                }

            }
            else // if the device needs to be removed
            {

                [self.deviceDictionary removeObjectForKey:deviceSerial];
                NSLog(@"Device removed: %@", deviceName);

            }
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception)
        {

            [self.deviceDictionary removeAllObjects];
            CFRunLoopRun();

        }
        @finally
        {

            NSLog(@"\n%@", self.deviceDictionary);

        }

    }
    else // name is nil
    {

        [self.deviceDictionary removeAllObjects];
        CFRunLoopRun();

    }

}
```

[image: memory leak info from instruments]

Comment: Are you sure they are really memory leaks?  I.e. do they accrete over time?  Is it the DeviceInfo that is "leaking"? That appears to be malloc()'d, but only free'd on notification.  How should it be free'd if there is no notification?

Comment: Instruments is telling me they are memory leaks. I guess I trust Instruments - should I not? I found a spot to call 'CFRelease(deviceNameCF);' which was leaking. I think you're right about DeviceInfo being the other source of leaks. Since I don't care about built-in devices, I moved all of the 'deviceDataRef = malloc()' and 'deviceDataRef->deviceName' code inside of a 'if (builtIn.integerValue != 1)' statement. This has significantly reduced leaks. I still get leaks when I plug in new USB devices however. I suppose because  a new DeviceInfo object is created.

Comment: There can be false positives;  especially if a subsystem is being tricky about how pointers are stored.   In this case, it sounds like you need to add some means of free()'ing the DeviceData structures outside of just the notification.   I.e. when do devices "go away"?

Comment: I believe each instance of DeviceData is released in `DeviceNotification()` via `free(deviceDataRef);` which is called when a USB device disconnects from the bus. Each deviceDataRef is created when a USB device connects to the bus. I added criteria to never create a deviceDataRef for an internal USB device (think built-in keyboard on a MacBook). Every deviceDataRef created _should_ only be for a removable device, which upon removal, frees the associated deviceDataRef. Maybe because Instruments has no way of knowing if or when each deviceDataRef will be freed, it assumes it must be a leak?

Comment: Sounds like there is a hole in the logic somewhere;  Are you *sure* that there is always a notification for every device before it goes away?  (In this case it sounds like they really are leaks).    Instruments detects leaks by scanning the heap and seeing if there is a pointer to the block anywhere.  If there isn't, it is marked as a leak (and that is why subsystems that "hide" pointers can cause false positives).  In your case, because the block is never free'd but you claim that it should be, it is worth investigating as a leak.

Comment: In my testing, yes, there is always a notification when 1) a device is connected, and 2) when a device is disconnected. When a device is connected, a deviceDataRef is created for the device. That deviceDataRef is then used in an `IOServiceAddInterestNotification` which uses `DeviceNotification()` as its callback when the device, among other things, disconnects. I ignore non-disconnect messages. However, when `DeviceNotification()` gets a disconnect message, it frees the deviceDataRef it was passed from the `IOServiceAddInterestNotification` callback via `free(deviceDataRef)`